# данные из html формы не передаются в php

Tags: php, html, post, submit

Всем доброго дня! Делаю сайт с подключением к бд, работа с которой осуществляется через форму HTML. Скрипт php должен по номеру из HTML выводить соответствующую позицию в бд. Все работало, а теперь не открывается HTML форма.

```
<?php

$dbase =  mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root');


if(!$dbase){
    $url = "error.html";
    header ("Location: $url");
}


else{
        $base = mysqli_select_db($dbase, 'millionaire rating');
        
}
        if(isset($_POST['number'])){   

        $num=$_POST['number'];
       
        $query = "SELECT Name FROM rating Where Id=$num"; 

        $result = mysqli_query($dbase, $query);
        
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        
        require_once('index.html');
        
        
    }

?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<form action="/index.php" method="POST"  >
    <Legend>Рейтинг миллионеров:</Legend>
    <div>
        <label>
            Номер в списке
            <input type="number" name="number" min="1" max = "10" value="1">
            <input type="submit" value="Передать">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
</form>
<div>Миллионер:
    <span><?php print_r ($row['Name']); ?></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Запускаю через openserver, показывает просто пустую страницу в браузере

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)